# How to get Meta data for a file in S3 bucket: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file in S3 bucket, I want to get the "Meta Data" info which is in below:

[image]

How can I do that?

I am getting a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error:

[image]

Code I have tried:

```
     const params = {
              Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
              Key: "abc"
            }
      const metaData = await s3.headObject(params);
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with your sample code?

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: no...@JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if you are providing the correct key for the file or not. as per the documentation this is how you get the metadata of a file

> await s3.headObject({
> Bucket: <BUCKET_NAME>,
> Key: <S3_PROVIDED_KEY>
> }).promise();

Comment: A link to the documentation where you found this would be helpful